Embed YouTube video without controls in react?
I want to embed YouTube video in my react app but I don't want the controls to be shown on the screen.
This is my current code but still this had no effect on control:
function ProductVideoGallery() {
  const videos = useContext(videoCollectionContext);
  return (
    <>
      <section className="min-h-full flex flex-col gap-12">
        {videos && videos.length ? (
          videos.map((vid) => {
            let videoSrc = vid.includes("?")
              ? vid + "&controls=0"
              : vid + "?controls=0";
            videoSrc += "&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1";
            return (
              <iframe
                key={vid}
                className="mx-auto my-8"
                src={videoSrc}
                title="Category Video"
                frameBorder={0}
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
                referrerPolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
                allowFullScreen
                style={{ width: "100vmin", aspectRatio: "16/9" }}
              />
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <p className="text-2xl">No video found</p>
        )}
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default ProductVideoGallery;


controls=0 works fine in my test, and the share code generator even still offers it as an option. What actual URL did the iframe get assigned, can you give an example?

The video URLs are pulled from API. But, roughly you can consider the following URL:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/LXb3EKWsInQ?si=CroGPlXf-M18g7K-
The controls=0 removes the controls but I'm unable to remove the title and share icons. I know youtube has deprecated it, but is there any way I can do so?

I don't think there is, at least not any officially documented one. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters
